# Bazel adds -MD -MF -frandom-seed flags by default - Why?

Tags: bazel, toolchain

I have a cc_toolchain configuration for a proprietary c compiler and I have ensured that the compilation commands are correct from the bazel output using the '-s' flag.

However, bazel adds the three compilation flags '-MD -MF and -frandom-seed' in addition to what I have specified.

My compiler does not recognize the -MD and -MF flags. No issues with the -frandom-seed.

How can I specify bazel NOT to add these flags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not add random seed, disable the corresponding feature, add:

```
random_seed_feature = feature(
    name = "random_seed",
    enabled = False,
)
```

and add `random_seed_feature` to list of `features` you pass to `cc_common.create_cc_toolchain_config_info()`.

For `-MD -MF` it gets more complicated. You could disable `dependency_file` feature in a similar manner, but the `hdrs_check` would fail expecting to find a dependency dump and I do not believe you can actually disable that for C++ action with cc_toolchain based on current implementation (or no readily available method comes to mind).

The question is, does your compiler still support dumping dependencies, just using different flag(s)? Then you can (even should) redefine the feature, for reference in https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc it currently for U*X-like systems looks like this:

```
dependency_file_feature = feature(
    name = "dependency_file",
    enabled = True,
    flag_sets = [
        flag_set(
            actions = [
                ACTION_NAMES.assemble,
                ACTION_NAMES.preprocess_assemble,
                ACTION_NAMES.c_compile,
                ACTION_NAMES.cpp_compile,
                ACTION_NAMES.cpp_module_compile,
                ACTION_NAMES.objc_compile,
                ACTION_NAMES.objcpp_compile,
                ACTION_NAMES.cpp_header_parsing,
                ACTION_NAMES.clif_match,
            ],
            flag_groups = [
                flag_group(
                    flags = ["-MD", "-MF", "%{dependency_file}"],
                    expand_if_available = "dependency_file",
                ),
            ],
        ),
    ],
)
```

If your compiler does not produce this file at all, I am afraid on top of disabling the feature you'd need to wrap its call and dump an empty file to where `dependency_file` is expected (essentially use a flag the wrapper understands, gets the file name and strips both from compiler call, writing an empty file for the check). You'd lose the headers checking for dependencies being correctly declared by by-passing it, but it would allow the build to proceed.

Alternatively, from scratch new cc_toolchain with own actions which does not incorporate the header checking could be an option.